# Google Colaboratory ServiceWorker Error On Chrome

Tags: service-worker, google-colaboratory

Whenever I open a Colaboratory Document I always get the same error message:

> NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The user denied permission to use Service Worker.

This is happening on chrome and my browser allows for ServiceWorkers (`chrome://serviceworker-internals/`), what's going on? Because the thing is all the code still runs.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Colab's output frames use service workers to support some functionality such as displaying richer graphs (Altair and Plot.ly).

The error message indicates that **third-party cookies** are disabled in your browser, this will prevent the browser service workers from working. The option should be configured under chrome://settings/content/cookies.

Comment: Which third-party cookies need to be enabled specifically?  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: I navigate to chrome://settings/content/cookies and changed cookies options, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I tried white-listing in chrome link (chrome://settings/content/cookies) the following:

```
https://[*.]googleusercontent.com:443
[*.]colab.research.google.com
```

Here it was the best approach, better than simply liberatin the 3rd part cookies
Seems to work so on.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two causes for this error:

1- you didn't allow cookies on colab domain, so you need to change you browser settings

2- you are using an adblocker