# Allow a Google Colab domain cookies on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-colaboratory

I am trying out Google Colab, but then I keep getting this pop up box that says:

```
Error

Could not access the resources needed to display output.
This is probably because third-party cookies are not allowed by your 
browser.

NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The user 
denied permission to use Service Worker.
```

While turn off `Block third party cookies` worked for me from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285485/google-colaboratory-serviceworker-error-on-chrome), I would like to keep the setting to be turned on at all times for the sake of our privacy.

Currently I will have to have another tab next to the Colab tab the so that after I have finished using Colab, I can turn it off right away and not to forget it. BUT I would have to do it every time I use Colab.

To solve this, I have tried to follow the [chrome help guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and added `https://colab.research.google.com` and `[*.]google.com` to the Allow whitelist on Cookies. However the error pop up would still show. I also tried `https://colab.research.google.com[/*]`, but chrome said its not a vaild domain.

Is there a way to allow Colab domain cookies for that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The output cell is an <iframe> element. It has a url like

https://jbe1910iol-colab.googleusercontent.com/v2/usercontent/8b5e8f2bbe60490e/outputframe.html

So, you can try adding `[*.]googleusercontent.com` to the whitelist as well.

Not sure if it will work though. Hope it does.

Comment: ...and it allowed anything from *.googleusercontent.com ;-) It would be nicer to have that service worker working under *.colab.research.google.com domain.

Answer (score 6):

For Google Chrome, go to the cookies settings page

1. Type this in the address bar

   `chrome://settings/content/cookies`
2. In `Allow` section, click add button.
3. paste this `[*.]googleusercontent.com`

That's all.

As Korakot Chaovavanich's explanation, I added steps