# Google Colab running any cell received javascript related errors

Tags: google-colaboratory

Received a browser white popup saying when executing any cells:

```
Error
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.

Please reload this page.
 DETAILS
```

I have tried re-login and restarted runtime, and no help. Strange is another notebook is fine.

OK[image]

Update: Just restarting browser and relaunched everything seemed to "fix" this.

Comment: Some additional context will help debug. What browser and version are you using? Does this reproduce in incognito mode? Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Do you have third-party cookies disabled?

Comment: I ended up just quitting my browser and restarted, and it's fine. I think it may be a one time fluke

Comment: I get the same error @kawingkelvin, Did you find any other way apart from restarting the browser? Did the variables get lost?

Comment: Not really. I don’t remember if the vars are all there. I believe they should still be there, esp. if you haven’t cleaned any cookie and still remain authenticated with google.

Comment: I have cleared all the cookies but it still get the same, I use this on Chrome

Comment: @TaiLy The only way out I found so far is to completely quit/shutdown the browser. Pls try this. If you find a better way, pls share as ans. I also found this is more likely to happen if you quit a tab with a live colab session and reopen the same notebook. I start to believe this is a bug. It has nothing to do with access expiration.

Comment: This helps a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289535/allow-a-google-colab-domain-cookies-on-chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restart browser. If someone find a better way, please post.

Comment: @SadafNiknam I haven't this problem for a while now, i think colab team has fixed something. I saw it once recently, which i resolved by terminating the session (not just restarting runtime), close the browser tab that has your notebook, reopen the same notebook, and start a new runtime. I did it all without restarting the main browser (i just close one tab).

Comment: I clear cache and browser history, disable Third-Party Cookies, open a new file and paste code, but it seems that all files have problems!

Comment: I still have the problem

Answer (score 10):

For those like me who tried all the given solutions but with no use ,the magic thing that worked for me in the end was to open colab using a vpn!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error on chrome. Every colab notebook I opened had this issue even if it wasn't connected to a runtime.
Restarting the browser didn't help.

***Clearing cookies of last 24hours (and restarting my system to be sure!) fixed the issue.***

Answer (score 1):

This may be because access to your Google account has expired or because your browser does not allow **third-party cookies**.

Comment: This issue hasn’t happened for a long while for me, and even if it does, it now is easily recoverable just refreshing the whole browser page. So i tended to believe it was a bug that got fixed. But since the root cause was not known, this thing can come back in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check your task manager on your laptop and see how full the disk is.
Mine was 100% so I searched “disk cleanup” on my Windows computer And got rid of temporary files and files downloaded from internet, etc. also clear cache and cookies on whatever browser you’re doing. And if you have synced your google chrome and Microsoft edge specifications as the same(cookies, extensions, etc) then get rid of both cache and other stuff on them as well. Also check 3rd party cookies

Comment: Do you have too many cells open on your Colab that aren’t needed? Start a new notebook with just the cells you need or get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using vpn solved this problem for me

Comment: Please provide some details to make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The library I'm using by default prints a large amount of info, which caused this problem for me. Restart the browser only works if it doesn't print that much again. Disabling the verbose info printing solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found when the notebook is heavy it is throwing up this error. For example there were so many plots in my notebook, that slowed it down and caused this problem. Also make sure you don't have multiple notebooks opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cleaning your trash/recycle-bin & temp files.
That worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling some AdBlock extensions works for me.