# Google Collab - Error "Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output. (...)"

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-chrome, cookies, collaboration

I am having problems running a Python notebook in Google Collab.

Please find below detailed information

Bug report for Colab: http://colab.research.google.com/.

•   Describe the current behavior: I've been using Collab for a while now and never had issues, but since yesterday it started showing an error. It says:
Error
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.
Please reload this page.

[image: Error in Google Collab notebook]

I have checked and none of the two possible problems it says are true.. my google account access and google-collab have not expired and I have 3rd party cookie enabled. (it is disabled only in incognito mode).

I have tried a bunch of things, including some pointed [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/745/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550349/google-colab-running-any-cell-received-javascript-related-errors)

Here are details of what I tried:

1-  Restarted chrome, disabled/enables 3rd party cookies and login again… failed.

2-  Restarted the machine… failed

3-  Restarted the browser with chrome://restart… failed

4-  Included domains https://colab.research.google.com and [*.]google.com  in white-list allowing the use of 3rd-party cookies… failed

5-  Tried to run the notebook under VPN… failed

6-  Enabled/disabled GPU usage… failed

7-  Included https://colab.research.google.com as javascript white-list of websites

8-  Restarted the machine several times after each change… failed

9-  Logged off/logged in my google account (… and restarted again).. failed

10- Deleted all Cookies, History Data (… plus additional restarts for each deletion)… failed.

11- Enabled “all cookies allowed”… failed.

12- Updated Javascript version, restarted the machine… failed.

13- Tried to run under incognito mode… failed.
Nothing worked…

•   Describe the expected behavior: It should execute the display of pandas dataset... it has done it several times before and suddenly stopped working.

•   The web browser you are using (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.): Google Chrome version Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Could you please help me?

Comment: Why are you posting a bug report here? Have you tried a browser that isn't chrome? have you checked the browser *developer* tools console for errors that may be more enlightening than what google pops up

Comment: Yes, I don't know if this is a bug or a problem, that's why I'm asking for help - I tried to provide as much as possible useful info. I tried with Microsoft Edge and the problem persists. I will check the browser developer tools as you suggested (thanks!) and post a follow up on this.

Comment: I repeat - Have you tried a browser that isn't chrome? - Microsoft Edge is NOT a browser that isn't Chrome - go on, give Firefox a chance to shine

Comment: Thank you for the tip - I have tried Firefox and the notebook runs with no problem so it is restricted to Chrome :) I also checked the developer tools console - there are a bunch of error messages but my knowledge of javascript is not enough to understand what's going wrong. Is it possible to post screenshot here?

Comment: I know that site produces hundreds of **warnings** - ignore those (for now) - concentrate on actual **errors**

Comment: I think the most relevant msg are: Autofocus processing was blocked because a document already has a focused element.
Could not load the JavaScript external_polymer_bin..RC00_393058641:1472
files needed to display output. ... but i don't have a clue of why is that.