# about Google Colaboratory errot at javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

GoogleColaboratory gives the following error: Please someone give me some advice.

The JavaScript file required to display the output could not be loaded.
This may be because your Google Account login access has expired or your browser does not allow third-party cookies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow a Google Colab domain cookies on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289535/allow-a-google-colab-domain-cookies-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Just close all tabs on the window and reopen.