# google colab error on google chrome browser - JavaScript files needed to display output

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I am having below error while using google colab on google chrome. It started coming up suddenly

```
Error
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google Account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.

Please reload this page.
```

I followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289535/allow-a-google-colab-domain-cookies-on-chrome)  using this [page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Callow-or-block-cookies%2Callow-or-block-cookies-for-a-specific-site) as some settings have changed. I have added `[*.]googleusercontent.com`  in the section `Sites that can always use cookies` using the below instructions

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More and
   then Settings.
3. Click Privacy and security and then Cookies and other
   site data.
4. Next to "Sites that can always use cookies," "Always
   clear cookies when windows are closed," or "Sites that never use
   cookies," click Add.

Apart from that I have tried below steps:

1. The google chrome>>incognito mode and firefox browser runs fine.
2. I have already restarted my machine and cleared my cookies.
3. My javascripts seem to be enable as they are on the setting `Sites can use Javascript`
4. My google account is fully functional and not facing any issues with gmail or any other site

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try with an incognito tab and see if anything changes

Comment: yes, an ingonito tab is not giving that problem. How could i get it working in the regular tab?

Comment: Have you disabled javascript usage on your browser?

Comment: how to do that? and why is that error popping up now only? I was not having that error 2 days back. what has changed?

Comment: should be on chrome://settings/content/javascript?search=javasc and should be on by default anyway. Other more dramatic solutions could be to use a VPN or reinstall the browser completely (is your google account completely functional also?)

Comment: google account works without any issues

Comment: do i need to disable java cookies or enable them? they are currently on the setting `Sites can use Javascript` and i am still getting that problem

Comment: They should be enabled, what you have now is correct. I will investigate further to help later

Comment: any update? thanks

Comment: Try to use VPN.

Comment: not an optimal solution as everything working without using VPN...which VPN service would you recommend? and if it is a browser related issue then why would VPN fix that?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289535/allow-a-google-colab-domain-cookies-on-chrome)

Comment: yes...it didnt work...i have referenced that page in my question too

Comment: Well, you can use any VPN/freevpn and it would definitely solve the problem. I faced this before and it was due to the network being restricted at my office.

Comment: i am trying veepn which is a free plug in for chrome..it is still giving same issue and I am at home so nothing is being restricted...could you recommend a particular vpn?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have too many cells open on your Colab that aren’t needed? Start a new notebook with just the cells you need or get rid of them.

Solution1: Disconnect your collab runtime and Restart your browser.

Solution2: Clearing cookies of last 24hours (and restarting the system) fixed the issue.

If anyone find any better approach, let me know.

There is an issue opened already https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/757