# Google Colaboratory ServiceWorker Error On Chrome / Vivaldi

Tags: cookies, google-colaboratory, vivaldi

This is the same issue as this post:
[Google Colaboratory ServiceWorker Error On Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285485/google-colaboratory-serviceworker-error-on-chrome)

...but I am using Vivaldi (1.15.1147.36 (Stable channel) (64-bit)) on ubuntu 18.04.

Upon opening a document, I am met with this:
NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The user denied permission to use Service Worker.

My question, specifically: Is it possible to make this work WITHOUT enabling all 3rd-party cookies? (The only Vivaldi setting I see is a check box for all 3PC's or none.)

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

From [the FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html):

> **Why prompt to enable third-party cookies?**
>
> Colaboratory uses HTML
> iframes and service workers hosted on separate origins in order to
> display rich outputs securely. Browsers require enabling third-party
> cookies to use the service workers within iframes. An alternative to
> enabling third-party cookies for all sites is to whitelist the
> following hostname in your browser settings: googleusercontent.com.